# HP Proliant ML350 G5 SAS HDD

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, drive-failure

I am getting problem in HP Proliant ML350 G5. Some few days back one of the SAS HDD failed. It was 146GB SAS 15krpm HDD. We got new one which is 146GB SAS 10k rpm HDD. Its on RAID 1(1+0) configuration.

We replaced the SAS HDD but its not rebuilding. We get message when rebooting server to do AUTOMATIC SERVER RECOVERY and we press F2. It starts recovery but after 20% (in HP System Management), it stops and nothing happen. It shows Logical drive degraded. and also in ACU, it shows ready to rebuild. We tried 2-3 times but it still the same. Whenever we restart it keep on saying Automatic server recovery.

Any suggestion, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Disk rebuilds can take many hours.  You might need to let it rebuild overnight.  Is the array very busy?  That will slow down the process.  I don't know about the E200i, but i know on the adaptec controllers, you can change the priority of the rebuild process.

Comment: Oh Lordy.... I'll write later.

Answer (score 4):

You've encountered the "Ready for Rebuild" error. This likely indicates that the drive can't finish its rebuild because the disk you replaced is having trouble reading from its partner drive. Essentially this means that you may have a failed disk and a *failing* disk.

I'm curious as to how you discovered the drive failure? Did you receive an alert? A pre-failure alert? Did you only notice when the disk health LED went red? How long had the drive been in a failed state before you replaced it?

Please post the full output from the `hpacucli` utility or a screenshot of your Array Configuration Utility. What operating system are you using?

If you have the HP System Management Homepage, you can watch the error counters on individual drives and see if they're incrementing.

Check your backups and be prepared to copy the data off the system or rebuild, as you *may not* be able to get out of this situation.

Also see: [Force LUN in a HP Smart Array to rebuild](https://serverfault.com/questions/282282/force-lun-in-a-hp-smart-array-to-rebuild/282286#282286)