# RAID 1 fault " Status Ready for Rebuild : Rebuild Percentage Complete 0%"

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, windows-sbs-2008, raid1, acronis

Our RAID 1 system partition failed on our Windows 2008 SBS (physical environment).  We still have disc 1 running but the 2nd disc in the raid is a failure.  To add to the complication, disc 1 has bad sectors but in a partition that is not required.  HP have sent out a replacement for disc 2 but the RAID rebuild has failed due to bad sectors on disc 1.

We have backups from last night (backup exec) and a Windows backup from a week ago.  We are at risk as we are running our Windows 2008 sbs on 1 hard drive with a bad sector.  If anyone has any solutions, please help?

We have a spare in our RAID 5 (same server).  Could I make the spare a standalone HD (not RAID), shut the server down and use Acronis (or similar imaging product) to image the good partitions on disc 1 to the standalone HD (the old spare from RAID 5).  We have time over the weekend when people are not using the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***"Ready for Rebuild"*** is one of the *worst* errors you can receive on an HP ProLiant system. This indicates that the drive can't finish its rebuild because the disk you replaced is having trouble reading from its partner drive(s). Essentially this means that you have a failed disk and a *failing* disk.

See the following:

[HP Proliant ML350 G5 SAS HDD](https://serverfault.com/questions/523868/hp-proliant-ml350-g5-sas-hdd/524001#524001)

[Force LUN in a HP Smart Array to rebuild](https://serverfault.com/questions/282282/force-lun-in-a-hp-smart-array-to-rebuild)

You can try a reboot (or power cycle... leave the machine off for a few minutes). Maybe that will jumpstart the process (it's worked once or twice for me in the past). If you have HP support, you can also pull an ACU diagnostic to see the specifics about the stalled rebuild.

As for moving data around, as long as you have good backups, anything is possible. But you know the details more than we do... Can you provide the disk sizes, array configuration, server model, controller model and firmware information? All of these matter, since they determine the options available to you. The output of the `hpacucli ctrl all show config` utility will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed.  Here's what i did:

Ran a backup on Thursday night of C drive.   I waited until Friday and ran check disc on the good partitions. all came back ok.  Shut down the server.  Unplugged the RAID 1 with the HD with bad sectors.  I then inserted 2 new HD's with and created a fresh RAID 1.  I then plugged the bad sector drive into a spare SATA port and boot the server with Paragon Disk Manager 14 Business.  I then imaged the good partitions from the old RAID to the new RAID.  All worked ok after a few hours.    restarted and everything came back up.