# Force RAID 1+0 HP Smart Array to rebuild

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have a RAID10 with status "Ready for Rebuild", but how can I force the rebuild?

```
# hpacucli ctrl all show config 

Smart Array E200 in Slot 0 (Embedded)     (sn: PA6C90N9SW82IU)

array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

  logicaldrive 1 (68.3 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 72 GB, OK)

array B (SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)

  logicaldrive 2 (2.0 TB, RAID 1+0, Ready for Rebuild) <---

  physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
```

Details about the RAID1+0:

```
# hpacucli controller slot=0 logicaldrive 2 show 

Smart Array E200 in Slot 0 (Embedded)

array B

  Logical Drive: 2
     Size: 2.0 TB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1+0
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 128 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 384 KB
     Status: Ready for Rebuild  <----
     Caching:  Enabled
     Unique Identifier: 600508B100104E395357383249550009
     Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d1
     Mount Points: None
     OS Status: LOCKED
     Logical Drive Label: A00E9989PA6C90N9SW82IU44B0
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
     Drive Type: Data
```

This is the controller:

```
RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array E200i (SAS Controller)
```

Thanks a lot!

-- edit

As requested, follow the 'crtl all show config' using Firmware Version: 1.78:

```
# hpacucli ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array E200 in Slot 0 (Embedded)
Bus Interface: PCI
Slot: 0
Serial Number: PA6C90N9SW82IU
Cache Serial Number: P9A3A0B9SW8426
RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
Controller Status: OK
Hardware Revision: A
Firmware Version: 1.78
Rebuild Priority: Medium
Expand Priority: Medium
Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
Surface Scan Mode: Idle
Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
Cache Board Present: True
Cache Status: OK
Cache Ratio: 50% Read / 50% Write
Drive Write Cache: Disabled
Total Cache Size: 128 MB
Total Cache Memory Available: 96 MB
No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
Cache Backup Power Source: Batteries
Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
SATA NCQ Supported: False
```

Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data

```
  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 68.3 GB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 17562
     Strip Size: 128 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 128 KB
     Status: OK
     Caching:  Enabled
     Unique Identifier: 600508B100104E395357383249550006
     Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d0
     Mount Points: /boot 99 MB
     OS Status: LOCKED
     Logical Drive Label: A0081154PA6C90N9SW82IUBFAF
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
     Drive Type: Data

  physicaldrive 2I:1:1
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 1
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 72 GB
     Rotational Speed: 15000
     Firmware Revision: HPD0
     Serial Number: BJL4P86004VM0826
     Model: HP      DF072BAFDT      
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps, Unknown

  physicaldrive 2I:1:2
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 2
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 72 GB
     Rotational Speed: 15000
     Firmware Revision: HPD0
     Serial Number: BJL4P86004RY0826
     Model: HP      DF072BAFDT      
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps, Unknown
```

Array: B
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data

```
  Logical Drive: 2
     Size: 2.0 TB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1+0
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 128 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 384 KB
     Status: Ready for Rebuild
     Caching:  Enabled
     Unique Identifier: 600508B100104E395357383249550009
     Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d1
     Mount Points: None
     OS Status: LOCKED
     Logical Drive Label: A00E9989PA6C90N9SW82IU44B0
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SATA, 750 GB, OK)
     Drive Type: Data

  physicaldrive 1I:1:5
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 5
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 750 GB
     Firmware Revision: HPG1    
     Serial Number: 9QK117ZV            
     Model: ATA     GB0750C8047     
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 1I:1:6
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 6
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 750 GB
     Firmware Revision: HPG1    
     Serial Number: 9QK10N2K            
     Model: ATA     GB0750C8047     
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 1I:1:7
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 7
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 750 GB
     Firmware Revision: HPGB    
     Serial Number: 9QK0X1DQ            
     Model: ATA     GB0750C8047     
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 1I:1:8
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 8
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 750 GB
     Firmware Revision: HPGB    
     Serial Number: 9QK2QK4H            
     Model: ATA     GB0750C8047     
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 2I:1:3
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 3
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 750 GB
     Firmware Revision: HPG1    
     Serial Number: 9QK119T8            
     Model: ATA     GB0750C8047     
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 2I:1:4
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 4
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 750 GB
     Firmware Revision: HPG1    
     Serial Number: 9QK10NMD            
     Model: ATA     GB0750C8047     
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

"Ready for Rebuild" status means that the rebuild is likely running into a read error from a partner disk. You may have another *failing* disk in the array. See: [Force LUN in a HP Smart Array to rebuild](https://serverfault.com/questions/282282/force-lun-in-a-hp-smart-array-to-rebuild/282286#282286)

- Did you recently replace a disk?
- Please provide the firmware revision of the Smart Array E200i controller you're using.
- Please show `ctrl all show config detail`

I'd check your backups and schedule time to power the system off and back on again. This could be a firmware issue, depending on what happened before this, or you may have the failing disk situation described above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
- Yes, we changed a failed disk
- Firmware 1.78
- I edit the original message with 'show config detail'
- We let the machine power off for a while, and then turn on again, but with the same error :(

Comment: Try updating the controller firmware. The current version is: 1.86

Comment: After the firmware upgrade and reboot, the recovery begins:       logicaldrive 2 (2.0 TB, RAID 1+0, Recovering, 1% complete)
Let's see if they will finish :)

Comment: Using Firmware Version: 1.86, after the reboot, the status is "Ready for Rebuild" again :(

Comment: @TiagoCruz Then you likely have a failed or failing disk in the array with read errors. There's also a slight chance that you need a disk firmware update. But at this point, you may not have options.